# Wordpress Internal Site Search Spam

Tags: wordpress, spam

I recently noticed a spam attack on Wordpress search flooded with thousands of weird urng, pharmacy keywords causing google to crawl index these pages. We discovered this on global index coverage on the Search console. This also causes our server to run high memory. I have massive drop in rankings after that spam.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS0lO.png)
[Wordfence live traffic with GEO blocking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur0op.png)

Firstly, I found that I had Nike shoe url that doesn't belong to us.
https://oursiteurl.ee/?r=rev4-104-1727610-5-20-65-nike+air+force+1+flyknit+ultra&addcart

But now I get thousands of url injections
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YViHR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlJkH.png)

I tried to block it with robots.txt but still google tries to crawl them.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: */feed/
Disallow: *?r=rev*
Disallow: /velje-sobivus-tabel/?r=rev*

Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

Can anyone know what to do?